# Exiting Continous Switch-CaseSstatement in Python

Tags: python, switch-statement

I've made a switch-case statement (used in C++) using a dictionary. The user should be asked for inputs continuously until he inputs "exit", so naturally I put the switch-case statement in a while-loop:

```
while True:
    action = input("Write action (insert, search, watershed, pixel, exit):")
    dict_action = {
        "insert": insert,
        "search" : search_r,
        "watershed" : search_w,
        "pixel" : get_pixel,
        "exit" : exit

    }
    dict_action.get(action,"Invalid")()
```

My function called "exit", that should break this loop and quit the program looks like:

```
def exit():
    return False
```

However, this does not terminate the while-loop. What should I do?

Comment: Use `sys.exit()` instead. However, this will kill your entire program.

Comment: You have to `break`, `return`, etc. directly from inside of the `while` loop.  So `'exit'` needs to be a special case that doesn't delegate to another function.  e.g. `if action == 'exit': break`

Comment: Both works, thanks MattDMo and 0x5453. The special case with if action == ... was preferable in my case. Don't forget to import sys if you use sys.exit()  :)